# How to retrieve both the array and the integer arguments of an age function?

Tags: apache-age

I have created a function for age which receives an array as an argument and outputs all it's elements except the head of the list. But I wanted to add a second argument to output the `N` last elements from the array. Although many age list functions retrieve the array as an `agtype *agt_arg`, the functions which get the scalar argument uses the `Datum *args` to retrieve the value. But using both the array and the scalar value as arguments, how should I proceed? Here is the function's [PR](https://github.com/apache/age/pull/1013/files#diff-771e9e18b770f8af0168e6ea71826246052f8b71a4be6da0aac29e89cb339c7e)

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you are using the `count` variable to iterate through the list right? So lets se you want to take only the last 3 elements of the list and the length is 10. If you do `count - n` you will get in this case 7, and then you can iterate from that index (e.g 7) until the end of the list.

At least thats what I understood correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: Yeah but I wanted the `n` to be part of the argument of the function so that the user can define how many elements from the tail of the list it is going to appear. Something like `age_tail([1,2,3,4,5], 2)` to show `[4, 5]`. But I don't know how to retrieve the second argument's integer value since it's being stored in an `agtype` data.

Comment: What if you take the second argument with `PG_GETARG_INTXX(1)`?  I would assume that the input of the user would be an integer right?

Comment: `PG_GETARG_INTXX(1)` doesn't work

Comment: XX should be replaced by the value that you want for your `INT` like `32` or `64. Also you can try `AG_GET_ARG_AGTYPE_P(1)` , and maybe cast it to scalar after some checks

Comment: Yeah I did that, replaced with 64 and didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help from the `agtype_add` function in [agtype_ops.c](https://github.com/apache/age/blob/master/src/backend/utils/adt/agtype_ops.c). For your case, what I can think of is that your function takes two agtype arguments and then retrieve the values as:

```
agtype *list = AG_GET_ARG_AGTYPE_P(0);
agtype *element = AG_GET_ARG_AGTYPE_P(1);
```

and then you can check whether the `element` is a scalar or not.

Answer (score 0):

Because `age_tail` is a variadic function, you should use the appropriate function to extract its arguments which is `extract_variadic_args`. This function also returns the types of the arguments which you can compare to `AGTYPEOID` and `INT4OID` to see if the first argument is agtype and second one is integer.

```
if (type == AGTYPEOID) 
  agt_arg = DATUM_GET_AGTYPE_P(arg);

if (type == INT4OID)
  count = (int64)DatumGetInt32(arg);
```

See the implementation of any variadic function  like `age_toInteger` to have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the integer as the second argument with this:

```c
int32 = PG_GETARG_INT32(1); // change 32 with the size of the int you need
```

Also don't forget to change the declaration in the age--1.3.0.sql file with the new argument to get recognized.

Answer (score -1):

The count variable is being used to iterate through the list's entries.

Let's say, you want to get the final three items out of a list that has a total of ten items. By deducting the number of components you wish to skip from the entire length of the list, you may determine the starting index. That would be 10 - 3 in this case, giving an index of 7. With this starting index in hand, you can loop through the list starting at index 7 and going all the way to the very end. In light of the list's overall length and the number of elements you want to obtain, this enables you to easily access and operate with the list's final three components.